# Mobile view in Browser doesn't work anymore

Tags: salesforce1-app

I used to user the Chrome developertools, and then typed /one/one.app to see the Salesforce 1 view and I was able to select between different devices etc. This now doesn't work anymore, and I get the following error:

> You can't access Lightning Experience
>
> The page you're trying to access is available from the Salesforce1
>   mobile app only. Please try again from a supported mobile device. Need
>   help? Ask your Salesforce admin.

Any ideas how I can fix this?
Tia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for this **one/one.app** is reserved for lightning experience.

After Winter 16 you can't use **one/one.app**

If you want to use mobile version then use emulator.

Salesforce1 Sandbox Simulator https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce1-sandbox-simul/mgknkgnenlhghpfpdcohmgiejlcaapih?hl=en

Salesforce1 Simulator  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce1-simulator/cknbjckicenodbiaejbmkjhldffonggp

Answer (score 1):

Also in addition to Ratan's answer you can still use `one/one.app`

> Just follow simple steps.

1. right click > Inspect element .
2. Now click on mobile icon and select any mobile.
3. now open in `one/one.app`. it will work without any problem.

Here is the [reference](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000204818&language=en_US) of what i suggest.

Cheers :)

Comment: is it, still we can use  this really ? @Tushar

Comment: @Ratan Yes we can use this. currently i am using this. You can check it.

Comment: The inspect element solution takes me to the same screen as the developer tools one. It doensn't work for me and I get the error message that I have posted in my original post.

Comment: did you select any mobile. Because ratan just test this thing and it is working as expected.

Comment: @Ratan Tushar Under the hood sfdc looks for browser user agent.Phones and Tablets have different User Agents than browsers .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava yes i know but this thing is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use one/one.app without inspect element and changing to mobile view.

1)Download chrome extensions like [agent switch](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US) .

2)Change your user-agent to IPad or IPhone.

3)Enter one/one.app to find it working